# array in object oriented programming

Tags: java, arrays, oop, methods

I'm a beginner in object-oriented programming and this is my first little project.I've heard that here everyone can help you in your code and this is my first time.Anyway, my problem why array doesn't store any value?

Here is the code:

```
    public class Information {
    private IT_Members[] member= new IT_Members[10];
    private int counter = 0;



Information()
{
    for ( int ctr=0;ctr<member.length;ctr++)
    {
        member[ctr] = new IT_Members ();

    }

}

public void Add(IT_Members member)
    {
        if(counter<10)
        {
        this.member[counter].setName(member.getName());
        this.member[counter].setDeparment(member.getDeparment());
        this.member[counter].setPostion(member.getPostion());
        this.member[counter].setID(member.getID()+counter);
        counter++;
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Add List Full"); 
    }
public void Display()
    {
        if (counter!=0)
        {
            for (int ctr=0;ctr<10;ctr++){
            System.out.println(this.member[ctr].getName()+
           this.member[ctr].getDeparment()+
           this.member[ctr].getPostion()+ 
           this.member[ctr].getID());


            }
        }
        else
        System.out.println("No member yet!");



    }
```

Here is the Main class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Interface {

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        IT_Members input1 = new IT_Members();
        Information input2 = new Information();
        int x=1;
        while(x!=0)
        {

        System.out.println(" \n[1] Add new student member. \n[2] View members.\nChoose now: ");
        int choose = in.nextInt();

        switch (choose){

            case 1:
              System.out.println("Name: ");
              input1.setName(in.nextLine());
              System.out.println("Deparment: ");
              input1.setDeparment(in.nextLine());
              System.out.println("Postion: ");
              input1.setPostion(in.nextLine());
              System.out.println("Student record has been added. ");
              break;

            case 2:

                input2.Display();
                break;

}
}
```

.........................................................................

```
public class IT_Members {
    private String name,deparment,postion;
    private int ID=1000;
    private int Flag=0;

    IT_Members (){


    }
    IT_Members (String name, String deparment , String postion ,int ID , int Flag){
     this.name= name;
     this.deparment=deparment;
     this.postion=postion;
     this.ID=ID;
     this.Flag=Flag;


    }

    public String getName (){

        return this.name;
    }
    public String getDeparment (){

        return this.deparment;
    }

    public String getPostion (){

        return this.postion;
    }

    public int getID (){

        return this.ID;
    }

    public int getFlag (){

        return this.Flag;
    }

    public void setName (String name){

        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setDeparment (String Deparment){

        this.deparment = deparment;
    }

    public void setPostion (String postion){

        this.postion = postion;
    }

    public void setID (int ID){

        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public void setFlag (int Flag){

        this.Flag = Flag ;
    }

    public String toStu()
    {

        String str = "";
        str = "\nName: " + this.name +
                "\nDeparment: " + this.deparment + 
                "\nPostion: " + this.postion +
                "\nID: " + this.ID;
        return str;        
    }
}
```

Please, I'm stuck with this I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: which line and which part of the code is you are having problem with? only extract out the problematic code and ask.

Comment: Insert input2.Add(input1) right before the break in case 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create every time a new Object and in the end you have to add in the list.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Interface {

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        Information input2 = new Information();
        int x=1;
        while(x!=0)
        {

        System.out.println(" \n[1] Add new student member. \n[2] View members.\nChoose now: ");
        int choose = in.nextInt();

        switch (choose){

            case 1:
              IT_Members input1 = new IT_Members();// this need to be here so that every time crete new object
              System.out.println("Name: ");
              input1.setName(in.nextLine());
              System.out.println("Deparment: ");
              input1.setDeparment(in.nextLine());
              System.out.println("Postion: ");
              input1.setPostion(in.nextLine());
              input2.Add(input1); // that was missing
              System.out.println("Student record has been added. ");
              break;

            case 2:

                input2.Display();
                break;

}
}
```

Comment: small mistake ruin everything :(  
Thank you so much.

Comment: it happens some time :)

Answer (score 3):

You never call the `Add` function in the `Information` class. Therefore you never initialize any of the array elements you then want to display.

You need to add `input2.Add(input1)` before you print that is has been added.